# Overlap in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a Layout problem. I have tried for hours to get it right but I cant figure it out.

It should be simple really.

I have a layout that looks like this: Fixed on the Screen are a header and a footer, in between these there is a scrollale view that displays some information and a button.

All I want that header, button and footer is fixed and the infomration fill the rest of the screen as good as possible.

The solution I have at moment almost works, the problem with it is that the information and the button overlap (the button is on top). The information only starts to scroll if it would overlap with the footer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/wrap_main" >

   <include
      android:id="@+id/in_header"
      layout="@layout/header" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/body"
        style="@style/wrap_body_with_footer_style"
        android:layout_below="@id/in_header" >

       <!--  This is a scrollable view --> 
       <include  android:id="@+id/job_description"
                 layout="@layout/job_description" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/btn_job_details_pick_up_submit"
                style="@style/btn_confirmation_style"
                android:text="@string/btn_job_details_pick_up_submit"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

      </RelativeLayout>

   <include layout="@layout/footer_krest_home_phone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So JobDiscription and Button overlap.

Any Ideas?

Thanks everybody.

Edit: Somebody mention LinearLayouts in the comments. I did try with LinearLayouts but I had the effect that the information, instead of contracting, pushed down the button so it was not fully visable anymore. If you have a solution to stop this pusing down effect, I'll happly change to LinearLayouts.

Comment: According to this, the button is below your information.  Also, does the attribute `layout_above` not work?

Comment: Try to use linear layout

Comment: Also, when using `<include>`, **always, always, always** override the `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes. Even if you override them with the same value.  There's a bug in which the `<include>` tag will simply ignore other attribute if those two are not included.

Comment: @DeeV I did not try and it does not matter. I dont want the button information not ontop of the information either. I want that the information starts to contract and offer scrolling insted of overflowing or underflowing the button.

Comment: @AndroidApple I did. The problem with linear layout is that the information pushes the button down to far, so its not fully visable anymore. If you have a way to stop that please write a answer, I will mention it in the question.

Comment: @nickick: I'm still confused.  If you apply `layout_above` to `job_description`, it will contract `job_description` to be between the top of its parent and the Button. You said `job_description` is a ScrollView, so if you have its width and height both set to `match_parent`, its dimensions will be bound to being in between the two and offer scrolling if its view is too large.  This sounds like what you are asking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments, I would also suggest positioning job_description above btn_job_details_pick_up_submit with `android:layout_above="@id/btn_job_details_pick_up_submit"`.

*Above* does not mean on top of something, it aligns the bottom of the view with the top of another one.